# rsyslog imfile wildcard in file path

Tags: rsyslog

I have following log files under my log folder.

```
xxxxxx.access.log
xxxxxx.access.log
xxxxxxx.access.log
```

I want all access.log to be monitored , so I tried but it is not working.

```
$InputFileName /var/log/nginx/*access.log
```

Is it possible in rsyslog ?
I am using rsyslog version 8.16

Answer (score 0):

It is possible in rsyslog 8.16 (I believe it was introduced in 8.6), but not using the old config format, you need to try the config format (Rainerscript), you would need to try something like:

```
input(type="imfile"
File="/var/log/nginx/*access.log"
Tag="access-logs"
Ruleset="access_logs"
addMetadata="on")
```

You would then need to extract the filename from the metadata so it can be saved in the right filename at the receiving end. You also need to define a Ruleset so that it can be processed.